# How to find memory usage of my android application written C++ using NDK

Tags: android, c++, memory-management, android-ndk, porting

I am porting a game written in C++ to Android using NDK. I need to know how much memory it consumes while running. I am looking for programmatically way to find the memory usage of Android application written in C++.

Comment: one way is to override the `new` and `delete` operator and do some bookkeeping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, you can check the native memory allocated/used with:

```
Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()
Debug.getNativeHeapSize()
```

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getNativeHeapAllocatedSize%28%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#getNativeHeapSize%28%29

Answer (score 8):

The two functions based on JonnyBoy's answer.

```
static long getNativeHeapAllocatedSize(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/os/Debug");
    if (clazz)
    {
        jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, clazz, "getNativeHeapAllocatedSize", "()J");
        if (mid)
        {
            return (*env)->CallStaticLongMethod(env, clazz, mid);
        }
    }
    return -1L;
}

static long getNativeHeapSize(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/os/Debug");
    if (clazz)
    {
        jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, clazz, "getNativeHeapSize", "()J");
        if (mid)
        {
            return (*env)->CallStaticLongMethod(env, clazz, mid);
        }
    }
    return -1L;
}
```

Comment: Actually these java methods are native methods themselves. According to http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_Debug.cpp (the cpp-source) you could use `mallinfo()` and then read the values for `uordblks` (`getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`) and `usmblks` (`getNativeHeapSize()`)

Comment: @super-qua, Tank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()` and`Debug.getNativeHeapSize()` return information about memory allocations performed by `malloc()` and related functions **only**. You can easily parse `/proc/self/statm` from C++ and get the **VmRSS** metric.

[See details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666544/3415353)